# How to connect MySQL with XAMPP server?

Tags: php, mysql, xampp, sqlyog

Hi I'm new to SQLyog program. And I kind of got this project from my lab in my college.
I have to make a website using database, specifically I have to make a simple social media for my department. The tables and queries is all done, but I can't connect my MySQLto XAMPP.
What do I do so my database could connect to XAMPP and I can make a web out of it?

Comment: What error msg you are getting? any screen shot?

Answer (score 0):

1. Open `xampp dashboard page`
2. Click on `phpMyAdmin`
3. click on `User accounts`
4. Click on `Edit privileges` :- User name:- root ,Host name:-local host
5. click on change password
6. Enter same password in `sqlyog`
7. click on `yes`

Comment: It's been long time since I touched this project again, I'm afraid I can't check wether this answer resolved the questiion or not.